remote_access(use_xarray=True) outputs TypeError
I am trying to access data in THREDDS using siphon using following code.
satcat = TDSCatalog(
"https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/satellite/goes/east/products/CloudAndMoistureImagery/CONUS/Channel02/current/catalog.xml"
)

sate_data = satcat.datasets[0].remote_access(use_xarray=True)

But this outputs following error:
TypeError: Vectorized indexing with vectorized or outer indexers is not supported. Please use .vindex and .oindex properties to index the array.
This is while following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TFohhk4xzI&list=PLg9E-Np_QpNVR2mdbnXLfd81-hmKk20sD&index=3

That error is the result of an incompatibility between the last release of siphon (0.9, pretty old at this point) and newer versions of xarray. We are actively working on a 0.10 release for Siphon, which should be out by the end of this week and will include a fix for this issue.
Current work-arounds:

Install an older release of xarray--2023.8.0 should work, I believe
Install Siphon from the main branch on GitHub: pip install --dry-run git+https://github.com/Unidata/siphon.git
Try forcing the use of opendap (instead of the cdmremote default): satcat.datasets[0].remote_access(use_xarray=True, service='OPENDAP')


The second one worked for me.
